# What is the difference between the quote function vs using quotation marks?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Why should I prefer this:

```
args: [{{ Values.somevalue | quote }}]
```

to this

```
args: ["{{ Values.somevalue }}"]
```

I feel like I read about the difference somewhere but I can find anything about what `""` do in the docs, they only mention `| quote`. But if the two lines I wrote above are equivalent, why would they bother creating the `quote` function in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/strings.go#L83) `quote`'s actual interesting property is that it can take arbitrarily many parameters, quotes each of them, and puts a single space between each

```
{{ $v := "foo" }}
{{ quote $v "bar" "baz" }}
{{/* "foo" "bar" "baz" */}}
```

If you had a need to include it in an extended pipeline, the function form could be convenient.

```
{{ list (quote $x) | toJson }}
{{/* ["\"foo\""] */}}
```

But otherwise it doesn't seem to do anything special, and in particular doesn't do any quote escaping.

```
{{ $x := "foo" -}}
{{/* All produce "foo": */}}
"{{ $x }}"
{{ $x | quote }}
{{ $x | printf "\"%s\"" }}

{{/* Not what you hoped for: */}}
{{ $y := "bar\", \"baz" }}
{{ $y | quote }}
{{/* "bar", "baz" */}}
```

(FWIW I almost always `{{ ... | quote }}`; but I think when I started learning Helm I also expected this to actually do escaping and it doesn't.)

Comment: It looks like you can also use double quotes inside braces to indicate a string literal, and then use `quote` to put quotes around them. For example if you want this text to appear in your manifest: `"{{ foo }}"` then in helm I think you need `{{ "{{ foo }}" | quote }}` which is useful for argo parameters...